# Intermediate stages in Apache Spark with no parent as well as child stages

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, rdd, data-partitioning

I am trying to understand the benefits of known partitioner in Apache Spark `(v2.2.3)`, for which I wrote the naive implementation of the Page-Rank algorithm, following the link example code - `https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/pagerank.py`

- `linksRDD` is of type `RDD[(String, Iterable[String])]`
- `ranksRDD` is of type `RDD[(String, Double)]`
- I have used a known `HashPartitioner` as mentioned in the code below.

```
val hashParts = new HashPartitioner(partitions = 10)
val partLinks = linksRDD.partitionBy(hashParts)

var rankUpdates = ranksRDD
for (_ <- 0 until numOfIters) {

  val contributions = links
    .join(rankUpdates)
    .flatMap({
      case (_, (outLinks, rank)) =>
        val numOfOutLinks = outLinks.size
        outLinks.map(x => (x, rank / numOfOutLinks))
    })

  rankUpdates = contributions
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .mapValues(_ * 0.85 + 0.15)
}

rankUpdates.saveAsObjectFile("SOME_PATH") //ACTION TO TRIGGER THE COMPUTATION.
```

- To compare I executed one more time without the partitioner. (two line changes as mentioned)

```
// NO PARTITIONER OBJECT IS PROVIDED/MENTIONED
val partLinks = linksRDD
val partRanks = ranksRDD
```

Now, for the code using the know `HashPartitioner` there are many stages created with only one task `partitionBy`, which don't have any parent stage neither do they have child stage/s. These stages are not associated with any action, just floating in between the DAG.

- I have circled the stages which do not have any dependency - [Screenshot of DAG with known `HashPartitioner`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSP3y.png)
- [Screenshot of all the stages with known partitioner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFgM7.jpg)
- [Screenshot of all the stages WITHOUT/NO known partitioner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcJO1.png)

Can anyone explain to me why are these stages created? As the summations of all shuffle read for the stages with known partitioner and without known partitioner comes out be approximately the same. Because of these additional stages, there is no gain seen in the amount of data being shuffled.